# Closing alert dialog using menu

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have an alert dialog with some items. I need to close the dialog when the user clicks the menu button without giving any options to close. How can I do that?

Here is my code

```
CharSequence[] cs = ques_cat.toArray(new CharSequence[ques_cat.size()]);
finalCharSequence[]css=ques_catidtoArray(newCharSequence[ques_catid.size()]);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Gropinion_Questions.this);
builder.setTitle("Choose Category");
builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        String ss = css[item].toString();
        getSubCat(ss);
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    if(alert !=null && alert.isShowing())
        alert.dismiss();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your host activity's, you will want to check if the user has gone to the menu and dismiss the dialog there:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    yourDialog.dismiss();
    return true;
}
```

Or you may intercept the menu key pressed event by adding this to your main activity:

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        if (yourDialog != null && yourDialog.isVisible()) {
            yourDialog.dismiss();
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP wants to close a dialog box that is currently shown with the MENU button . i believe the following is what he wants. Solution is tested in the emulator.

```
void buildDialog(){
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();  
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setTitle("Close with menu button");  

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) { 
                dialog.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```